# React Native Download JSON but not displaying in Flatlist

Tags: json, react-native

I am trying to download the JSON. React Native is downloading the json but I am not sure why Flatlist is not displaying the items. If I change the data={dummyData} in flatlist to data={MyList} then, the flatlist is able to display.

```
let viewableItemsChanged = null;
const dummyData = GrabData('http://hunterdata.serveblog.net/10record.json');

const MyList = [
    {"id":"0","title":"MyBook0","url":"URLBook-0","image":"image-0" },
    {"id":"1","title":"MyBook1","url":"URLBook-1","image":"image-1" },
    {"id":"2","title":"MyBook2","url":"URLBook-2","image":"image-2" },
    {"id":"3","title":"MyBook3","url":"URLBook-3","image":"image-3" },
    {"id":"4","title":"MyBook4","url":"URLBook-4","image":"image-4" },
    {"id":"5","title":"MyBook5","url":"URLBook-5","image":"image-5" }];


async function GrabData(TheURL) {
  let abc = [];
  try {
    let response = await fetch(TheURL, {headers: {'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'}});
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log(responseJson);
    return responseJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

const renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return <View><Text>{item.title}</Text></View>
}

const List = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      style={styles.list}
      data={dummyData}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />

  )
};
```

Comment: You didn't call the API so no data is fetched.

Comment: But the console.log showed  LOG  [{"id": "0", "image": "image-0", "title": "MyBook0", "url": "URLBook-0"}, {"id": "1", "image": "image-1", "title": "MyBook1", "url": "URLBook-1"}, ...... It downloaded the JSON

Answer (score 1):

there is an issue with your code. you are calling the `async function` without `await` keyword. so it returns undefine response like this. `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`

Please Try this solution.

```
import React, { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
    import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
    
    const Item = ({ title }) => (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
    
    const App = () => {
       
        
        const [data, setData] = useState([])
       
         useEffect(() => {
            apicall();
        },[])
    
        const apicall = async () => {
            let dd = await GrabData("http://hunterdata.serveblog.net/10record.json");
            setData(dd)
        }
        
        const GrabData = async (TheURL) => {
            try {
                let response = await fetch(TheURL, {headers: {'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'}});
                let responseJson = await response.json();
              
                return responseJson;
              } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
              }
        }
    
    
        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <Item title={item?.title} />
        );
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item?.id}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
      },
      item: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
        padding: 20,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 32,
      },
    });
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Your code works. But I do not understand it. Example const Item = ({ title }) => ( ) ... what is the meaning ? Also on this.     const [data, setData] = useState([])   
     useEffect(() => {
        apicall();
    },[])

Comment: please read the react-native basic documentation so you will understand it.

Answer (score -1):

You should activate the functions in componentDidMount also try states instead of const

Comment: Sorry...I am quite new. How do I do that ?

Comment: Hey, this is not an answer.